# Cannot open some websites when using OpenVPN in Ubuntu

Tags: openvpn

I use OpenVPN in my Ubuntu.  I can access every site, except YouTube, Facebook, and Twitter.  Chromium says that the site cannot be reached, that it took too long to connect.

I tested this in other systems running Lubuntu, but I have the same problem.  I also tested on Windows to see if this happens there when using OpenVPN, and this does not happen.

What could be causing this issue, and how do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you. What I did is that in FireFox I go to `Preferences > Advanced > Settings`, And change several times `Configure proxies to connect to Internet`.

Doing this I can visit all of sites.

But there might be a deeper reason for that and I think it relates to some configurations within dns.

But I don't know how to resolve the problem with changing my dns.